# inclination / cliff faces from raster heighmap

Tags: qgis-2

I've got a raster heightmap source. I'm working with Quantum GIS.

Extracting contour lines from that is easy, thanks to the plugin. However, I would like to go one step further and find out where on the map the inclination is how steep. More specifically I want to find places where the steepness is above some value x.

Mathematically, I figure calculating the distance between the contour lines would give me what I'm looking for, but is there a plugin or something other that already does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Raster Terrain Analysis Plugin](https://www.qgis.org/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_raster_terrain.html) calculates slope.

You can then use the Raster Calculator to select values above value x.

Comment: That is probably the solution. My input data isn't clean enough to work straight away (get Moire effects), but that's probably something I can solve with a bit of extra work.

Comment: Oh the wonders of cleaning raster data for analysis.  I am no guru when it comes to raster analysis, but it seems every time I need to do something (mostly within ArcGIS), the first thing I always did was convert my raster to type integer.  Analysis tools seemed to play nice when my raster had been converted.  Sometimes this required thinking outside the box a bit but nonetheless it was a very helpful step.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? Because I'm kind of stuck on the cleanup part. I've tried edge-detect in Photoshop as a preliminary test, but that didn't exactly get me what I want to.

Answer (score 0):

Triangulate the isolines ([constraint triangulation](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html)) and calculate the slope of the triangles. [CGAL](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/index.html#Section_2D_Triangulations_Constrained) will triangulate polygons too.